# Passing login details in PHP class

Tags: php, oop, object

Few weeks ago start play with php classes. I made progress and pretty much understand how it works. But I still struggle to get data from another files.

I read lots of examples and still not understand.

My example:

```
<?php
class test
{
   private $server;
   private $db;
   private $user;
   private $pass;

     function __construct($var1, $var2)
         {

        // do something... validate var1 and var2
        // do $this->var1=$var1; etc


          }

       // other functions
            ... 

       public function login($parameter1)

     {
       $this->new=$parameter1;

      my connection and here i would like to use 
     $this->server,
     $this->db,
        ...

     }
}

?>
```

My index.php file:

```
<?php
include 'connections.php';
$class = new test(var1, var2);
$class -> login($parameter1);
?>
```

connection.php:

```
<?php

  $server = 'something';
  $db = 'something';
  $user = 'something';
  $pass = 'something';

?>
```

My question is how to use and declare connection string inside class from external source? Only one way to pass these details via `new test(var1, var2, $server, ...);`? Or am I doing something wrong?

Please don't but this question as duplicate because I am asking explain.

Comment: Is your problem with getting data into class or getting data from one file to another?

Comment: @MatejKormuth how to get(pass) properly login details into class  from external file. Same i would like to keep all queries in separate file

Comment: You can pass arguments to the constructor if you need data at object's construction time, and you can pass arguments to method but that's what you are doing. I don't understand, where is the problem with "passing login details to class"?

Comment: @MatejKormuth   I have one external file with configuration(login details settings etc) and in a class i'm using functions to connect to the server, read data from the server. And i don't want declare login details many times in diferent classes i would like to declare once in congif file and then get these data when i call the class. Basically when i call to the class that data should be there

Comment: @MatejKormuth other thing is i seen lots if times then people declare properties same i did but they not passing anything via new test(). So why they declaring?

Comment: Well then, depending on the way you store your configuration data, get it and pass it to constructor / another method. If you want you can also use getters and setters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Database{
   public static function newConnection(){
      return mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
   }
}

$db = new Database;
$conn = Database::newConnection
$test = new test();
$test->login($conn);
```

at your login method

```
public function login($conn){
   $sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
   ..........
}
```

It is a very common pattern at OO instead to create new Database connections at your classes make it someone esle job and just pass the references as parameters

**How to pass data to Class variables**

```
class Foo{
   public $classVar1;
   public $classVar2;

   public function __construct($var1, $var2){
      $this->classVar1 = $var1;
      $this->classVar2 = $var2;
   }
```

now lets init the Foo clas

```
$foo = new Foo('var1', 'var2');
```

from now on if you echo

```
echo $foo->classVar1
```

you will get the output var1

you can also use your class variable inside your class like this

```
public function anotherFooclass(){
   echo $this->classVar1;
}
```

if you invoke the class

```
$foo->otherFooClass();
```

you will get the output var1

Comment: So do send login details or sql query to the class i need to declare in $foo = new Foo('var1', 'var2'); ?

Comment: or like this `$server = 'something';
  $db = 'something';
  $user = 'something';
  $pass = 'something'; $test = new test($server, $db, $user, $password);`

Comment: Yes it is. With this way you ''pass" data to your class variables.

Answer (score 1):

here what comes in my mind ...

1) use define

```
define('db_server', 'something');
define('db_db', 'something');
....
```

This defines a constant, which are known everywhere.

2) use parameter

```
function login($parameter1, $server, ...)
```

3) use static function

```
public class Config {
  public static function getDbConfig() {
    return ['server' => 'something', 'db' => 'something']; 
  }
}

$dbconfig = Config::getDbConfig()
```

Hope this gives you an idea.

Comment: thats right, that is the answer to how to get the values into that class.
but for sure, its more a hack ;-)

Comment: for this problem with the database connection, i would prefer a singleton

Comment: @dios231 But i have seen lots of classes have variables like my class but i not understand why how they works

Comment: @dios231 i mean how to pass data in these variables

Comment: look edit, if you have other question please comment my answer